# Removing array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How we can remove an array entry from :

```
            var a = [],b = [],c = [],d = [];
            var multi = {
                a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d
            };
```

Means if i want to remove `a` array from multi . What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `delete` keyword:

```
delete multi.a
```

**Example:**

```
var a = [], b = [], c = [], d = [];
var multi = { a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d };

delete multi.a;
console.log(multi);
```

**Result:**

```
Object
  b: Array[0]
  c: Array[0]
  d: Array[0]
```

**Docs:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

> The delete operator removes a property from an object.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a property of an object, [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) it.

```
delete multi.a
```

It doesn't matter what the value of the property is (it can be an array or anything else).

The variable `a` will still contain a reference to the same array though. If you want to get rid of it entirely, you have to overwrite that variable or allow it to fall out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) it:

```
delete multi.a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [],b = [],c = [],d = [];
var multi = {
   a: a, b: b, c: c, d: d
};
delete multi.a;
console.log(multi);
```